# Using linq to populate list of classes

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table similar to below:

```
Data {
    id varchar(50),
    pId uniqueidentifier ,
    fId uniqueidentifier ,
    xid uniqueidentifier,
    flag smallint 
}
```

The table contains a lot of duplicate rows since pId and fId is a 1:n relationship and fId to xId is a 1:n relationship too.

I want to query this table and populate a obj as below:

```
class P
{
    Guid id;
    List<F> fList; 
}

class F
{
    Guid id;
    List<X> xList; 
}


class X
{
    Guid id;
    byte flag; 
}
```

I am learning Linq. Any solutions using Linq to populate class P from the table would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You really shouldn't ask a yes or no question.  The answer to your question is simply, "yes" and I don't think that would be helpful to you.  Also, what have you tried?  What problems have you run into implementing a solution on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return `IEnumerable<P>` (not sure about converting `smallint` to `boolean` but other stuff should work)

```
var query = from p in context.Data
            group p by p.pId into gp
            select new P()
            {
                id = gp.Key,
                fList = (from f in gp
                         group f by f.fId into gf
                         select new F()
                         {
                             id = gf.Key,
                             xList = gf.Select(x => new X() { id = x.xid, 
                                                              flag = x.flag })
                                       .ToList()
                         }).ToList()
            };
```

Comments:

`gp` will contain all rows corresponding to some pId, in other words - it returns all fId, which related to pId.

`gf` will contain all rows from previous result which relate to some fId (i.e. all xids related to fId)

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what i was looking for. I will accept the answer after the time limit.

Comment: @Chai if F also has flag, then flag will be duplicated many times, you can't be sure that all flag values are same, so I'd go with grouping by composite key. Change grouping to this `group f by new { f.fId, f.flag } into gf` and when creating new F object: `id = gf.Key.fId, flag = gf.Key.flag`